# #include <bits/stdc++.h> with Visual Studio does not compile

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have seen recently that `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` includes *every* standard library and STL include file. When I try to compile the following code segment with Visual Studio 2013, it prints an `error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'bits/stdc++.h': No such file or directory`. But it works perfectly fine with Code::blocks. Is there any way to avoid this error?

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

}
```

I saw in some post that

> ... the header file is not part of the C++ standard, is therefore non-portable, and should be avoided. ...

But I think the file is helpful in contest programming.

Comment: That isn't a standard header. Don't rely on implementation details. If you really need a header that includes all the others (you really don't want that), use your own.

Comment: I would've used my own but it won't be recognized in the popular OJ sites like uva,loj  etc. Plus why it does not work in VS2013? Just wanting to know that as it works in codeblocks.

Comment: Because they're using different standard library implementations.

Comment: It doesn't work in VS2013 because only GCC (used by Code::Blocks) has that file.  This is like asking why you can't `#include <windows.h>` on a Linux system.

Comment: Voting to reopen. This is most definitely not a duplicate of [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095/4561887), and it's definitely a stretch to say it is. This question seeks explanations of why it doesn't work and would be benefitted by solutions of how to make it work anyway. The other question seeks neither of those two things. A link to that other question should be posted in the comments here as a _related_ question, not a duplicate.

Comment: @GabrielStaples: I would say the other question is related to such extent that it becomes nearly a duplicate. The most voted answer literally says: for avoid errors with the header drop its usage. And the duplicate question explains: the header is gcc-specific; this is exactly the reason why it doesn't work in Visual Studio. "... and would be benefitted by solutions of how to make it work anyway" - There are solutions "copy the header from gcc" and "create the header by yourself". Do you want to post another solution? If not, then I assume the duplicate to be the best state.

Comment: @Tsyvarev, I don't personally want to add another answer at this time, but I do think the "copy the gcc header" solution is a great solution, and could use enough improvement that I'd like to open the question to allow someone to provide an improved solution to better demonstrate and explain that.

Comment: In C/C++ Configurations inside vs code, make sure you have set Compiler path because by default it is not set.

Also, you may set IntelliSense mode to windows-clang-arm64

Answer (score 52, accepted):

> Is there any way to avoid this error?

Yes: don't use non-standard header files that are only provided by GCC and not Microsoft's compiler.

There are a number of headers that the C++ standard requires every compiler to provide, such as `<iostream>` and `<string>`.  But a particular compiler's *implementation* of those headers may rely on other non-standard headers that are also shipped with that compiler, and `<bits/stdc++.h>` is one of those.

Think of the standard headers (e.g. `<iostream>`) as a "public" interface, and compiler-specific stuff (like everything in `bits/`) as the "private" implementation.  You shouldn't rely on compiler-specific implementation details if you want your program to be portable to other compilers — or even future versions of the *same* compiler.

If you want a header that includes all the standard headers, it's easy enough to write your own.

Answer (score 17):

To use `bits/stdc++.h` preprocessor in Visual Studio you need to download the `stdc++.h` file from the given below link.

- Download file from the following link: https://mega.nz/file/feIXkY7a#ECkj1bZKA-72dYzatuKsgBQJ4lMe0v81sfxuhyKCNk0
- Create bits folder in the following directory: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\include`
- In some cases, the folder `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\` might be empty. In such cases, go to vs code and type `#include <` at the top. You'll get auto complete suggestions . Along with each suggestion, a path should be visible for every suggestion. Copy the path and paste it on the file explorer. The path will land you inside the same `include` folder mentioned above.
- Make a new directory with name `bits` and paste the stdc++.h file inside the `bits` folder.
- Restart Visual Studio if it is running and use it

Comment: Please avoid using external links to websites like mega. They will likely be broken in a near future.

Comment: Here is the reliable way to find stdc++.h. Search for "gnu.org stdc++.h" by your favorite search engine. It should appear in the first hit or the first few hits.

Comment: Here is a link to the file of interest in the GCC source code directly: https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/precompiled/stdc%2B%2B.h As predicted by @JérômeRichard, the link in the answer is already dead.

Answer (score 6):

This is non-standard header file, which is known to be part of the libstdc++, which typically comes with GCC. However VS comes with Microsoft's own implementation of the STL, which doen't contain such file. I'd recommend to stop using it and instead include necessary standard headers, like `<iostream>`, `<vector>`, `<string>`, `<algorithm>` etc.

Answer (score -1):

To use `bits/stdc++.h` you can create `bits` folder in below directory in your computer and paste the `stdc++.h` file in bits folder and your good to go.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include
```

Answer (score -2):

My answer will be for Enterprise 2015, Version 4.8.03761, update 3.

When you installed codeblocks, MinGW (the (Min)minimalist (G)GNU Compiler Collection (GCC) for (W)Windows) was also installed. Or you could install it separately.

I believe this problem is because Visual Studio can't find bits/stdc++.h in its Include Directory (Project -> YourProject Properties -> Configuration Properties -> VC++ Directories -> Include Directories -> press the drop down arrow -> <Edit..> -> Evaluated Value).

You need to go to that directory, and paste the entire bits folder from your MinGW installation, mine was in (C:\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\8.2.0\include\c++\mingw32).

No errors on my side once that was done.
I hope this answer will help anybody looking to solve this problem.

Thank you.

Comment: You really need to use the text formatting options.

Answer (score -3):

Install latest version of `MinGW` from the official [release](https://www.mingw-w64.org/)

Then copy the bits folder from

```
C:\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\mingw32\bits
```

to...(VS2019)

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\<type>\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\include
```

Note the  would be "Community"/"Professional" based on the VS installation and licensing.