# Different results obtained when using MSVC compiler and GCC compiler.How can I achive the same ouput as gcc in msvc(visual studio)?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Trying to run the following shortest path algorithm code. When I tried running the code on visual studio 2019, there was an unexpected output for the same code which I ran on a GCC compiler.

Is there any way I can get the same output in the MSVC compiler(Visual Studio 2019)?

The code:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#define M 10
#define N 10
using namespace std;

class Node
{
public:
    int x;
    int y;
    int dist;

    Node* parent;

    Node(int ax, int ay, int adist, Node* aparent)
    {
        x = ax;
        y = ay;
        dist = adist;
        parent = aparent;
    }
};

void printPath(Node* node)
{
    if (node == NULL)
    {
        return;
    }
    printPath(node->parent);
    std::cout << "{"<< node->x << ", " << node->y <<"}"<< std::endl;
}

bool isValid(int** mat, bool** visited, int row, int col)
{
    return ((row >= 0) && (row < M) && (col >= 0) && (col < N) &&
        (mat[row][col] == 1) && (!visited[row][col]));
}

void BFS(int** mat, int i, int j, int x, int y)
{

    int row[4] = { -1, 0, 0, 1 };
    int col[4] = { 0, -1, 1, 0 };
    // construct a matrix to keep track of visited cells
    bool** visited; /*= new bool[M][N]; */
    visited = new bool* [10];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        visited[i] = new bool[10];
        memset(visited[i], false, sizeof(visited[i]));
    }
    // create an empty queue
    std::queue<Node> q;

    // mark source cell as visited and enqueue the source node
    visited[i][j] = true;
    q.push(Node(i, j, 0, nullptr));

    // stores length of longest path from source to destination
    int min_dist = INT_MAX;
    // run till queue is not empty
    Node* node = NULL;
    while (!q.empty())
    {
        // pop front node from queue and process it
        node = &(q.front());
        q.pop();
        // (i, j) represents current cell and dist stores its
        // minimum distance from the source
        i = node->x;
        j = node->y;
        /*cout << i << "----- " << j << "\n";*/
        int dist = node->dist;
        if ((i == x) && (j == y))
        {
            //  cout<<"dasdas";
            min_dist = dist;
            break;
        }

        // check for all 4 possible movements from current cell
        // and enqueue each valid movement
        for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++)
        {
            // check if it is possible to go to position
            // (i + row[k], j + col[k]) from current position
            if (isValid(mat, visited, i + row[k], j + col[k]))
            {
/*                  std::cout  << ":::::::::::::::::" << std::endl;*/
                    // mark next cell as visited and enqueue it
                visited[i + row[k]][j + col[k]] = true;
                q.push(Node(i + row[k], j + col[k], dist + 1, node));
            }
        }
    }
        //std::cout<<"dasdasdas";
    if (min_dist < INT_MAX)
    {
        std::cout << "The shortest path from source to destination "
            "has length " << min_dist<<endl;
                printPath(node);

    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Destination can't be reached from given source";
    }
}

int main()
{
    int mat[M][N] = {
        { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1 },
        { 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1 },
        { 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1 },
        { 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1 },
        { 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1 },
        { 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0 },
        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1 },
        { 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0 },
        { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1 },
        { 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1 },
    };

    int** array2D = 0;
    array2D = new int* [10];
    for (int h = 0; h < 10; h++)
    {
        array2D[h] = new int[10];
    }


    for (int hs = 0; hs < 10; hs++) {
        for (int ws = 0; ws < 10; ws++) {
            array2D[hs][ws] = mat[hs][ws];

        }

    }


    for (int hs = 0; hs < 10; hs++) {
        for (int ws = 0; ws < 10; ws++) {
            std::cout << array2D[hs][ws] << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }


    BFS(array2D, 0, 0, 7, 5);
    return 0;
}
```

Expected correct output in **gcc**:

```
1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 
0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 
0 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 
1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 
0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 
1 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 
0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 
0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 
1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 
0 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 
The shortest path from source to destination has length 12
{0, 0}
{0, 1}
{0, 2}
{1, 2}
{2, 2}
{3, 2}
{3, 3}
{4, 3}
{5, 3}
{5, 4}
{6, 4}
{7, 4}
{7, 5}
```

MSVC compiler output(incorrect):

```
1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1
0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1
0 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 1
1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1
0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1
1 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 0
0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1
0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0
1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1
0 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1
Destination can't be reached from given source
```

Comment: It is highly unlikely that you compiled this code using the Visual C++ compiler. The first line of the code prevents the compilation on a MSVC implementation.

Comment: why are you entering the trouble of manually allocating arrays of arrays when the dimensions are fixed and when you could use `std::array` / `std::vector` ?

Comment: you even start with a static 2d array `mat` but immediately copy its contents to `array2D`. why?

Comment: [Why should I not `#include <bits/stdc++.h>`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h)

Comment: [#include <bits/stdc++.h> with visual studio does not compile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25337300/include-bits-stdc-h-with-visual-studio-does-not-compile)

Comment: I'm fairly sure this is undefined behaviour: `node = &(q.front()); q.pop();` when using `node` after the `pop`